# SQL Server Query Optimization - MultiJoins in table of 20 million records

Tags: sql-server

Below mentioned query is run against tables which have huge number of records - upto 22029464.... And this is taking on an average around 20-25 mins in execution. Is there any scope of optimizing or rewriting this in different. Required indexes exist on all table, query plan show no missing index requirement

```
SELECT  stg.*
    FROM    dbo.s_NIIT_ResultValues stg
    WHERE   stg.resultId IN ( SELECT    resultId
                              FROM      Data_NIIT.dbo.NIIT_Results )
            AND ( stg.resultIntValueId IS NULL
                  OR stg.resultIntValueId IN (
                  SELECT    resultIntValueId
                  FROM      Data_NIIT.dbo.NIIT_ResultIntValues )
                )
            AND ( stg.resultBoolValueId IS NULL
                  OR stg.resultBoolValueId IN (
                  SELECT    resultBoolValueId
                  FROM      Data_NIIT.dbo.NIIT_ResultBoolValues )
                )
            AND ( stg.resultStringValueId IS NULL
                  OR stg.resultStringValueId IN (
                  SELECT    resultStringValueId
                  FROM      Data_NIIT.dbo.NIIT_ResultStringValues )
                )
```

Comment: Why aren't you just LEFT JOINing toResultIntValues, ResultBoolValues, ResultStringValues ? Seems like it would be a lot more efficient and be essentially the same, and a LOT easier to read and understand.

Comment: Query plan, table definitions, and all indexes and keys on those tables please.  "*Required indexes exist on all table, query plan show no missing index requirement*" is a false conclusion, the query plan recommendations are far from complete in this particular determination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my first question is "why you will need so many records at a time ?" why not use paging.

Secondly do use "with (nolock)" and don't use "*",mention column name.

Thirdly i will change my join to left or use "Exists clause".

```
SELECT  stg.mentioncolumnname,stg.mentioncolumnname1
    FROM    dbo.s_NIIT_ResultValues stg with (nolock)
where exists(SELECT    resultId
               FROM  Data_NIIT.dbo.NIIT_Results with (nolock)
                 where resultId=stg.resultId)
and exists(

  SELECT    resultBoolValueId
                  FROM  Data_NIIT.dbo.NIIT_ResultBoolValues with (nolock)
                  where ((stg.resultBoolValueId IS NULL) or (resultBoolValueId=stg.resultBoolValueId))
 )
 and exists(

  SELECT    resultStringValueId
                  FROM  Data_NIIT.dbo.NIIT_ResultStringValues with (nolock)
                  where ((stg.resultStringValueId IS NULL) or (resultStringValueId=stg.resultStringValueId ))
 )
```

Another way :There are 3 join with table dbo.s_NIIT_ResultValues .

Join only one table with dbo.s_NIIT_ResultValues in 3 diff editor and see which of the resultset is minimum  and tell us.